# A decreasing sequence of integrable functions with the limit of the integral exist

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Question: Prove or disprove: If {${f_{n}}$} is a decreasing sequence of integrable functions such that $lim\int f_{n}$ exists in $\Bbb R$, then $lim\int f_{n}=\int lim\ f_{n}$.

Attempt: I think this is right. Since $lim\int f_{n}$ exists in $\Bbb R$, then each function is finite a.e.. Then we can use LDCT to with dominated function be max{|$f_1|,|lim\ f_n|$}. Is this proof right?

Comment: I don't see any argument showing that $\max \{ |f_1| , |\lim f_n| \}$ is integrable. It could be possible (in principle) that $|\lim f_n|$ is not integrable. Since $\{ f_n \}_n$ is decreasing, I think you should use monotone convergence theorem.

Comment: @Crostul You are right. Maybe I can use monotone convergence theorem to $f_1-f_n$ first then I have $\int f_1-lim\ f_n$=$lim\int f_1-f_n$ then I get the answer here. is this right? And so existence of $lim\int f_n$ avoids infinity-infinity?